# Problem running convert: action on makefile using docker desktop

Tags: docker, makefile

Recently, I've downloaded a github repository(https://github.com/greatjapa/dbc2csv) and it contains a makefile with the following code:

```
convert:
    ./dbc2dbf.sh
    mkdir -p data/csv
    python3 dbf2csv.py
```

and when i try to execute it, the following error appears:

```
C:\Users\miche\dbc2csv>docker run -it -v C:/Users/Barry/Downloads/filestoconvert:/usr/src/app/data dbc2csv make
./dbc2dbf.sh
./dbc2dbf.sh: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "do")
make: *** [Makefile:2: convert] Error 2
```

How cain I fix it?

Comment: The problem seems to be in the `dbc2dbf.sh` script itself, not in anything you've included in the Dockerfile.  Do you get the same error if you run the script as the main container command, rather than the Makefile wrapper?  Is there a possibility you've built the image locally with DOS line endings, which could cause problems like this?

Comment: At the very least we can't help without knowing what the text is at line 1 of the `dbc2dbf.sh` file, since that's where the error is from (`./dbc2dbf.sh: 1: Syntax error` means line 1 of that file).  If you can't figure it out please edit your question and cut and paste that info into it, with formatting.